# Dynamically change Font Awesome Icon on Radio Button Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class of Font Awesome icon on selected Radio button, I am using following code

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-default btn-round">
        <input name="P_AGND_ID" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check red2"></i>RADIO 
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-default btn-round">
        <input name="P_AGND_ID" type="radio" value="2" />
        <i class="ace-icon fa"></i>OPENING BIDS
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-white btn-default btn-round">
        <input name="P_AGND_ID" type="radio" value="3" />
        <i class="ace-icon fa"></i>EXTENSION AWARDING
    </label>
</div>
```

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=P_AGND_ID]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name=P_AGND_ID]:not(:checked)').find('i').removeClass('fa-check');
    $('input[name=P_AGND_ID]:checked').find('i').addClass('fa-check');
});
```

I have also created a jsFiddle if some one help me [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ziona/gL2pj3ec/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `find()` only finds descendants of the selected elements, what you want is a sibling (because `<i>` is a sibling of `<input>`)

So you can use:

```
$('input[name=P_AGND_ID]:not(:checked)').siblings('i').removeClass('fa-check');
$('input[name=P_AGND_ID]:checked').siblings('i').addClass('fa-check');
```